# Problems with lexapp.c in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: c, visual-studio-2005, lex

I have a strange problem with running a program in Visual Studio 2005. Explaining what I am doing :

1. Project was in Visual Studio 6
2. Converted Project to Visual Studio 2005
3. Got an error in lexapp.c (This is a C file generated from Unix machine after I feed it the app.l file)

   ERROR - Initializer not a constant

   `FILE *yyin = {stdin}, *yyout = {stdout};`
4. Changed the above code to

   `FILE *yyin, *yyout;`

   and put the following code in `yylex()`

   `yyin = stdin; yyout = stdout;`
5. Code compiles & builds fine now.
6. Debugged to find that it seemed to going in an endless while loop inside lexapp.c.

Same code works fine in Visual Studio 6. I am unable to figure out why the way in which I declare `yyin` or `yyout` would cause an issue. Is it possible to get a lexapp.c file which is complaint with Visual Studio 2005 because I believe what I changed in step 4 is causing the problem. Would appreciate any input from you guys out here. However, I am new to lex & yacc.

Regards,

Comment: The type of stdin is `FILE *`, hence the type of `{stdin}` is `FILE *[1]`. That `FILE *[1]` would be silently converted to a `FILE **` in C. You shouldn't store a `FILE **` value in a variable that stores `FILE *` values. In fact, a C++ compiler (which you are using, by the way) will emit an error where a C compiler doesn't in this situation. Why are you using a C++ compiler to compile C code?

Comment: Compile C code with a C compiler and C++ code with a C++ compiler, link C code to C++ projects using your C++ linker and you won't have problems. Compile C code with a C++ compiler and many problems will arise.

Comment: I have set the compiler option to compile it as C code. Doesn't that make a difference ? All I wanna be able to do is debug the code using Visual Studio 2005 or higher without putting print statements all over.

Answer (score 1):

"Compile as C" in VC++ is the equivalent of "-std=C89" in gcc, where gcc usually compiles as GNU99 (C99 with extensions). The current C standard is C11. The VC++'s "compile as C" lacks the features added by C99 and C11. I would regard it as an outdated C compiler when configured to "compile as C", or an up-to-date C++ compiler when configured to "compile as C++". This explains why code that compiles with gcc might not compile with MSVC++. I'd suggest that the original code made use of C99 features that aren't in MSVC++'s C89 support.

The solution is to convert the C99 code to it's equivalent C89 code, which it seems you have already done (or started doing), or compile it using a C99/C11 compiler (eg. gcc).

Comment: Thanks @modifiable lvalue. I can compile & build the code just fine now. What I dont understand is changing the way yyin & yyout are initialized is causing lexapp.c to run into an endless while loop. Whereas, the same code is running fine in Visual Studio 6 without any issues.